# 3D scene not visible in render

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, transparency

I can see the **test scene** which comprises of the 3D text **Loom-Tastic** in the VSE, but when I render it disappears, Why?

***VSE***

[image]

***RENDERED RESULT***

[image]

here is a link to my

[blender file](https://app.box.com/s/gv8kmtowzx9blxcx0c0l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that the loom - tastic text wasn't rendering. this was due to the fact that the wrong layer was selected in the test scene:

[image: Notes]

Change the selected box to the one the green arrow is pointing at, and your problem will be fixed

Comment: Thanks David, that worked! How do I know which scene layers to select?

Comment: The one shown in the image is correct. you can see what layer your object is on by looking for the orange dot on the render layers tab at the bottom of the 3D view.